# Is indirect exposure to non-alcoholic beer dangerous for cats?

Tags: cats, diet, safety, poison

That may be a strange question but my kittens expressed a lot of interest in bottle of non-alcoholic beer I was drinking. They tried to lick the bottle and started licking me around my lips. I could not find any information regarding non-alcoholic beer when I tried to google it (only about alcohol). I don't see any signs of poisoning/intoxication (especially that I hadn't really let them enjoy what they are doing) but should I worried about their well being?

Worried new cat daddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De-alcoholized beer isn't actually zero alcohol, but it's very, very low (typically 0.5% ABV). That may be low enough to be harmless to a cat, but bear in mind that there's a major weight difference between us and them, so percentages needed to feel effects are different. Also that, in the end, alcohol is just bad for them and there's nothing positive to be gained there by allowing it.

The other reason I would discourage it is to discourage them when there's beer that has normal volumes around. If your cat has a taste for it, they may go after it and, well, they can't read to see there's a difference and avoid the risk.

tl;dr - I wouldn't allow it.

Comment: Thanks but I wasn't talking about giving them beer - I don't drink from their bowls so they don't drink from mine. I was referring to indirect drinking (I drunk some and there are traces on my lips, they drink by grooming me).

Comment: My point is that unless you're watching them like a hawk, cats get into a lot. I would discourage access.

Comment: I see. As long as before mentioned is fine I think I will be able to guard a single bottle (with the same care I'm guarding tea/coffee due to caffeine).